# Como extrair frases de um texto em Java?

Tags: java, string

Recentemente li um artigo que analisava o tamanho das frases de vários autores. Era um estudo estilístico de suas obras.

Como faço para ler um texto (com vários parágrafos) e extrair as suas frases? Preferencialmente em Java.

Answer (score 6):

Começando com o exemplo mais simples, assumimos que uma frase termina em ponto, seguido de um espaço (ou quebra de linha):

> Ela é carioca. Ele, paulista.

Bastaria um `split()` da String usando o ponto seguido de qualquer caractere de espaço, lembrando de escapar os caracteres com `\`:

```
s.split("\\.\\s+");
```

Porém temos que considerar também ponto de exclamação e interrogação:

> Onde esteve? Estava preocupada!

Para isso vamos utilizar um **positive lookbehind** do RegEx:

```
s.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s+");
```

Porém temos que considerar que algumas frases podem estar entre aspas simples ou duplas, no caso de diálogos.

> "Hoje estou velho?" — disse o meu pai.

Para isso vamos incorporar esses elementos no pattern, lembrando que o travessão é um caracter que pode ser removido ou mantido (dependendo do desejo do programador):

```
s.split("(?<=[.!?]|[.!?][\'\"])\\s+");
```

Mas ainda temos as abreviaturas. O que fazer quando um ponto seguido de espaço não indica o final de uma frase, mas sim uma abreviatura (Sra. para Senhora, Sr. para Senhor, Dr. para Doutor, etc)?

> A Sra. Pereira conheceu Geoge W. Bush.

Aí utilizamos um **negative lookbehind** do RegEx:

```
String pattern = "(?<=[.!?]|[.!?][\'\"])(?<!Sr\\.|Sra\\.|Dr\\.|Dra\\.|W\\.|)\\s+";
```

Note que o RegEx já começou a ficar complicado, e o ideal é colocar as abreviaturas em uma estrutura a parte para checá-las uma a uma. Podem surgir casos mais complexos (ex: U.K.) que precisam ser tratados.

Em resumo, você pode sofisticar bastante o seu código, mas considere que este é um problema de [Processamento de Linguagem Natural](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processamento_de_linguagem_natural), e ainda não há solução perfeita. Os melhores algoritmos alcançam de 90% a 99% de acurácia dependendo do texto.

Se precisar de uma solução mais robusta e precisa, sugiro pesquisar pelo [Stanford NLP Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) que possui algoritmos em Java para isso.