# Como colocar \" em uma String?

Tags: java, string, formatação, eval

Eu estou tentando evaluar um código PHP usando Java, pra isso eu preciso substituir no código todas as `"` por `\"`. O problema é que o Java também tem esse caractere de escape pra por `"` em uma String.
Me disseram pra usar `\\"`, mas o resultado foi esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como digitar isso? Ou alguma forma de executar PHP dentro da JVM? (Estou fazendo uma gambiarra que se resume em executar no terminal `echo "codigo" | php`... Está funcionando, mas tem esse probleminha com as `"`).
Obrigado

Comment: Cuidado ao 'evaluar' códigos. Se tiver alguma possibilidade de entrada do usuário, seu programa pode ter um grande risco de vulnerabilidade.

Comment: Tente usar `\\\"`, As duas primeiras barras iram ser transformadas em uma só para a string, e o `\"` será o caractere literal `"`.

Comment: Foi resolvido usando ``\\\"``, Obrigado pessoal. Quanto aos cuidados ao "evaluar", tenho um controle sobre isso, obrigado por avisar =)

Comment: @MateusA., coloque seu comentário como resposta, para que o Nathan possa marcar como correta, ajudando assim a comunidade.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como indicar numa regex que os símbolos '(' e ')', os parênteses, são uma das alternativas numa lista de símbolos em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172741/como-indicar-numa-regex-que-os-s%c3%admbolos-e-os-par%c3%aanteses-s%c3%a3o-uma-das-al)

Comment: Pra rodar PHP na JVM: http://j-php.net/

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar `\\\"`, as duas primeiras barras iram ser transformadas em uma só, para a `string`, e o **\"** será o caractere literal ".

Comment: Ué, lugar de resposta é na resposta não nos comentários. não entendi o -1

Comment: Acho que foi porque seria mais camarada da sua parte orientar ao mateus transformar comentário em resposta do que copiar os comentários dele na integra ;)

Comment: Pode ser, mas se o Mateus colocar a resposta, eu removo a minha de boas, ao invés de ser negativado por uma resposta que está correta :|

Comment: Por isso eu disse "orienta-lo a converter o comentario em resposta" ;)

Comment: Pq não orientaram já, ao invés de me negativar ?

Comment: Por que você não o orientou? Isso é algo que qualquer um pode fazer, inclusive demonstra coleguismo :)

Comment: Sim, eu o fiz agora! Enquanto estavas me dizendo para fazer :D

Comment: Nao precisava do -1, essa pergunta é muito simples e já foi respondida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172750/63618) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190107/63618) por esse motivo não respondi e marquei como comentário, além de poder abranger uma outra resposta pois ele não mostra o código completo. Meu unico erro foi não sinalizar, desculpe... Mas pode manter a resposta.

Comment: Desde quando entrei aqui no stack, não entendo o pessoal respondendo nos comentários, serio. Comentário é pra comentar, resposta pra responder. Por que dessa mania?

Comment: @LucasHenrique peguei essa mania no SO, e podem ser por [vários](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4217/366679) motivos.

Comment: @MateusA. Eu acho que entendi, seria tipo: Não tenho tempo para fazer uma resposta detalhada, não tenho certeza se esta totalmente correta, ou só para dar uma guiada pro caminho certo.

Comment: @LucasHenrique sim, tanto por isso, quanto também não gosto de responder questões que eu sinalizo (terceira resposta do post no meta).

Comment: @MateusA. faz sentido...